# How to prevent my app/layout from displaying header and footer on sanity studio

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13, sanity

I am having this issue where my header and footer from the app are appearing on my sanity admin page, and I assume it has to do with the layout.tsx file but I cannot seemt to fix it or find solutions online. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
        <body className={`${inter.className} overflow-x-hidden no-scrollbar`}>
          <Header />
          {children}
          <Footer />
        </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

[image: header appearing in sanity studio]

Comment: Sorry to ask and then answer, but luckily I figured it out.  *shrug emoji*
I used pathname to find the target page(s) and conditionally render the components on the root layout.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-pathname

`code
const pathname = usePathname();
const isSanityStudio = pathname.startsWith('/studio');

{/* Conditionally render Header if not in Sanity Studio */}
{!isSanityStudio && <Header />}
{children}
{/* Conditionally render Footer if not in Sanity Studio */}
{!isSanityStudio && <Footer />}
`